# PHP: Using spaces in associative array indices

Tags: php, associative-array

Is this bad practice/can cause problems?

```
$_SESSION['stuff to keep']
```

As opposed to calling `str_replace()` on the indices.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is bad practice, but not because of the space.

```
// file foo.php
$_SESSION['stuff to keep'] = 42;

// file bar.php
if ($_SESSION['stufft o keep'] == 42) frobnicate();
```

Here, your code is silently misbehaving, and the bug can take a while to be found. Good practice is to use a PHP-enforced name, such as a class constant:

```
$_SESSION[Stuff::TO_KEEP] = 42;

if($_SESSION[Stuff::TOO_KEEP] == 42) 
// error: no constant TOO_KEEP in class Stuff
```

You may then define that constant to any constant you find interesting or readable, such as `"stuff to keep"` (with spaces). Of course, `extract()` and casting to `object` won't work anymore, but you shouldn't be doing that anyway with your session.

Allowing user-entered text into session keys is, of course, a blatant security fault.

Comment: I would say there is one exception. If you have a language array I think its best practice to put the translatable phrase also in your key.

Answer (score 10):

You can do that, it'll work -- and even if I don't generally do it when I set the keys of my arrays "by hand", it sometimes happens when I get the keys from a file *(for instance)*, and I've never had any problem with this.

Maybe this could cause some kind of a problem if you are using the [`extract`](http://php.net/extract) functions, though. If it creates variables with spaces in their names *(don't know if it will)* it'll be difficult *(but not impossible)* to access your variables.

Comment: +1 Good point - extract will throw an error (warning?) if it is asked to extract an array that has invalidly named keys

Answer (score 6):

It won't cause a problem, but array keys are usually considered like variable names so should be chosen with the same considerations

Answer (score 0):

Seems like adding unnecessary whitespace in my opinion... I don't usually use spaces. If you do, though, make sure you quote the array keys.