# spacing between square brackets of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array where I would like to put spaces between the [] like :

```
$array[South Africa]=array();
```

But I can't... why this is not possible?

Comment: Why do you need the spaces? Can you not use underscores or something? Here is a SO regarding spaces: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003036/php-using-spaces-in-associative-array-indices

Comment: Do `$array['South Africa']` then?

Comment: I think better practice would be to do an underscore and if the key needs to be displayed for output in a formatted way (like a loop or something) just `str_replace("_"," ",$key);`. Something like that is probably better than a space.

Comment: look as @Rasclatt pointed it out you  can have space `$array['South Africa']=array();` it might be giving you error message as `south Africa` is not in `' '` single quete. Thanks

Comment: Yes I use str_replace("_"," ",$key); but I don't understand why spaces don't work . Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is:

```
$array['South Africa']  = array();
```

By not placing quotes around strings, PHP will first check if it is a constant, and if not assume you want to specify the string stated (and generate a warning).

This would work without a space (other than the warning and being bad practise) but with the space PHP thinks the string/constant has ended after 'South' and expects an `]`. What you have specified will result in a syntax error:

```
 unexpected T_STRING, expecting ']'
```

I personally would avoid using spaces for names/keys anyway but the above explains the problem you are having if you must do this.